# Why does n choose k always yield a whole number?

Tags: probability, factorial

I'm just wondering why the n choose k formula

$n \choose k$ = $\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$

always gets you a whole number. I know that obviously there can only be a whole number of "ways" to choose k items in n items, but I'm more interested on how the factorials divide.

Answer (score -1):

Note that $k<n$. So when you write out what $n!$ contains, you will see $k!$ and $(n-k)!$ are included.

Comment: It's reasonably obvious that they're both included separately, but is it really obvious that *both* are included?

Comment: I'd say it isn't trivial

Comment: if a number  x is divisible by y and z , that  does not mean x/(y*z) is an integer.

Comment: @cyberboy that wasn't the point.

Comment: @Argyll , but this is the fault in your reasoning. here x = n! , y = k! and z = (n-k)! , you are saying that x is divided by y , and x is divided by z, but this does not mean x is divisible by y and z simultaneously , which is what we have to prove for showing it as whole number

Comment: Please don't assume what I am saying.